# ImageMagick not working on IIS 8.5 and PHP 7.1

Tags: php, iis, imagemagick, imagick

I'm not able to activate ImageMagick on my Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5 and PHP 7.1 installation.

- PHP Version 7.1.19
- Loaded Configuration File -> C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.1\php.ini
- Path var = C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16;C:\Windows\system32;....;C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.1\;
- php_imagick.dll in /ext available
- extension=php_imagick.dll in php.ini

But the extension will not loaded or shown in `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

I have no idea?!

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.1\ext\php_imagick.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

Comment: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.1\ext\php_imagick.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Does the file exist? (that would be my first idea, called a little something called diagnostics(`php_imagick.dll in /ext available` whe're not talking Linux are we?)) According to PHP it does not. If it does and the error still pops op, its unable to access it.

Comment: File is existing and accessible on windows server 2012 r2

Comment: Then the second dianogtic step, give access to the application to that file

Comment: Are you mixing 32-bit and 64-bit apps? Does your Imagick need ImageMagick 6 rather than 7?